# Are there any cards that turn creatures into land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are dozens of cards that turn land into creatures, but are there any cards that turn creatures into land ?

Comment: Path to exile does that indirectly :)

Comment: I just want to point out that if you're doing this for ramping or something, Cryptolith Rite gives all your creatures "tap to add 1 mana of any color to your pool"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are four cards that explicitly turn creatures into lands.

- [Life and Limb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life%20and%20Limb) makes all Saprolings Forests.
- [Song of the Dryads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Dryads) turns any single permanent into a Forest
- [Imprisoned in the Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Imprisoned%20in%20the%20Moon) turns any creature, land, or planeswalker into a land with no subtype that can only tap for {C}.
- [Ashaya, Soul of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashaya%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Wild) turns all creatures you control into forests.

In addition, there are 4 cards that can make arbitrary creatures copies of specific creature permanents: [Cytoshape](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cytoshape), [Infinite Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Infinite%20Reflection), [Echoing Equation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Echoing%20Equation), and [Mirrorweave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirrorweave). If you make a land into a creature (with a card with Awaken, for example), and then cast one of those spells targeting that land, the other creature(s) will become copies of the land.

Finally, any creature that enters the battlefield as a copy of a creature permanent (i.e. [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone)) or can become a copy of a creature permanent (i.e. [Shapesharer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shapesharer)), can become a copy of an animated land, which will result in it being just a land.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting that this really hasn't been done yet. I was hoping to find something that turned creatures into lands and removed their state of being creatures for a bit of sillyness, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: The problem is that making nonland permanents into lands is easily abusable. If you could turn any creature into a land, you could follow that up with Planar Cleansing to have the only creature on the battlefield. Plus, you could use something like that to avoid any effect that targets nonland permanents, like Detention Sphere.

Comment: It's not so much that it's abusable - there's very little that would be more abusive with this sort of card than the numerous other type-changing effects.  It's just that the rules interactions that come about from making traditionally non-land permanents into land get decidedly awkward.  Note that there are _very_ few 'creature-into-X' effects because of just these interactions.

Comment: ha! Thanks for keeping your answer updated with Imprisoned in the Moon!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is utilizing [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone) and friends alongside manlands (or effects which animate lands).

Example: Pay {G} to turn a land into a creature with the first ability of [Kamahl, Fist of Krosa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kamahl%2C%20Fist%20of%20Krosa). Then, pay {2}{U} to turn a Shapeshifter you control into that land with the activated ability of [Shapesharer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shapesharer). (Note: Shapesharer is a legal target of its own ability.) The creature will become a land until your next turn and will *not* be a creature, because continuous effects such as Kamahl's are not copiable characteristics.