# Permanent to let a creature tap for two mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, recommendations

I know there are cards like [Gemhide Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gemhide%20Sliver) which let slivers tap for mana. Convoke lets all creatures do this once. [Paradise mantle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Paradise%20mantle) gives a creature this ability. But these examples only let the creature(s) tap for one mana.

Is there a permanent that lets creature/creatures tap for two mana rather than one?

I know there are creatures that can tap for 2 or more mana (like [Incubation Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Incubation%20Druid) and [Gyre Engineer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gyre%20Engineer)) but I want to give a creature the ability rather than have a creature with the ability.

Comment: Convoke doesn't actually allow you to tap creatures for mana. It allows you to substitute tapping a creature for paying the mana. Cards that care about you adding mana, or tapping permanents for mana, will not "see" creatures tapped for Convoke.

Answer (score 6):

A few cards do allow creatures to be tapped for 2 mana, each with its own restrictions:

- [Grand Architect](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grand%20Architect) has the ability "Tap an untapped blue creature you control: Add {C}{C}. Spend this mana only to cast artifact spells or activate abilities of artifacts."
- [Joraga Treespeaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Joraga%20Treespeaker) has the ability "Elves you control have '{T}: Add {G}{G}.'" as long as it has at least 5 level counters.
- [Sachi, Daughter of Seshiro](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sachi%2C%20Daughter%20of%20Seshiro) has the ability "Shamans you control have '{T}: Add {G}{G}.'"

Comment: FWIW: There are ways around these restrictions, but they require additional cards.

Answer (score 4):

Murgatroid99 gave excellent answers for what you specifically asked for.  However, another route is to increase the mana generated by the mana source.  Say for example, your creature is equipped with [Paradise Mantle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Paradise%20Mantle) (there are lots of ways for creatures to generate mana.  That's just one.)  Then

- [Nyxbloom Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nyxbloom%20Ancient) will cause it to generate 3X mana.
- [Leyline of Abundance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Abundance) will cause it to generate an additional {G}.
- [Mana Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mana%20Reflection) will cause it generate 2X mana.
- [Kinnan, Bonder Prodigy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kinnan%2C%20Bonder%20Prodigy) will cause it to generate an additional mana.

Alternatively, you could [turn the creature into a land](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/are-there-any-cards-that-turn-creatures-into-land), and [use any of a number of techniques](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5Btap%5D%20%5Bmana%5D%20%5Badditional%5D) for increasing the mana generated by a land.

- [Ashaya, Soul of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashaya%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Wild) turns all creatures into lands.
- [Song of the Dryads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Dryads) turns any one creature into a land.

Answer (score 3):

You could combine [Kinnan, Bonder Prodigy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=479712) with standard mana-dorks, or turn all your creatures into mana-dorks using [Song of Freyalise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443067). [Mana Reflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489848) works with creatures, too.

Comment: Song of Freyalise on its own will not allow a creature to tap for two mana though.

Comment: @bautista this is why the sentence is structured as it is - two parts, obviously being connected.

Comment: @Erik the structure is actually really ambiguous